# How do I go about allowing a user to make a profile in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to make a profile for a user I generated with Devise and did this (in Rails 4):

```
rails g scaffold Profile first_name:string last_name:string school:string user:references
```

and then this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profiles
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :school   #where does this go in rails 4?
end
```

I want to know if this is the right way of doing this type of thing, or what should I do instead?

I also considered just adding all these fields directly to the User model through a migration...

Please any links and suggestions to do this correctly would really help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with a Users Profile page.

```
$ rails generate controller Users show
```

and in your routes file

```
devise_for :users
match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user
```

Users controller

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```